# Proving that $Im(T) = Im(TT^*)$ (hermitian adjoint)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space of finite dimension, and $T:V \to V$ a linear map. Prove that $Im(T)=Im(TT^*)$.

Proving that $Im(TT^*) \subseteq Im(T)$ was not a problem, but I'm having trouble proving the other direction. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $im(T^*)=\ker(T)^\perp$.

Comment: You mean I should prove that $Ker(TT^*)^\bot \subseteq Ker(T^*)$ ?

Comment: Note that $V$ can be decomposed as the direct sum of $\ker(T)$ and $\ker(T)^\perp$. So the image of $T$ is merely $T(\ker(T)^\perp)=T(im(T^*))=im(TT^*)$.